# What is LGT in BASIC?

Tags: basic

I'm trying to port a program written in Rocky Mountain BASIC to GWT, and I'm stumped by this statement:

```
1040 Cfs = 0.75/((LGT(Reyns)-2)^2)
```

`1040` is the line number. `Reyns` is a Reynolds number; the formula has to do with fluid flow. `LGT` is the mystery. I don't recognize it; it does not appear elsewhere in the program as far as I can see. I assume it's a BASIC function. Any guesses?

Answer (score 6):

It's the common logarithm (base 10) of a positive numeric expression assuming you're using [Series 80 HP Basic](http://www.ebbsoft.com/hp/hpbasic.htm).

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.ebbsoft.com/hp/hpbasic.htm, LGT is a function for

> common logarithm (base 10) of a positive numeric expression